# The meeting was postponed _____ (for/due to/owing to?)lack of quorum

Tags: exam-questions

> The meeting was postponed **owing to** lack of quorum.

This is from a sentence improvement MCQ which has the following options :

A. due to
B. because of
C. for
D. No improvement

Can anyone tell me which is the best option to choose among the given options? I think  *because of* is a synonym of *owing to* so it can be eliminated but which one to choose among options A,C and D?

Comment: A, B and D all seem like equally valid answers to me.

Comment: **C** is the only one which doesn't fit there, the reason: I don't know, that just doesn't sound good; peharps because **for** is likely to be used in positive contexts while your statement conveys a negative sense. Nonetheless, **A** and **B** look very alike, so I would opt for **due to** which sounds more formal to my ears.

Comment: Interesting.  To me **owing to** sounds more formal, probably because I happen to know that during the first half of the twentieth century, **due to** was widely derided by prescriptivists as supposedly incorrect (except when preceded by a form of *be* - which it isn't here, since the *was* is part of the expression *was postponed*).